# Functional dependencies and BCNF

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Hi everyone this is my first post here. I have a relation like this

`Relation R = (CustomerNr, CustomerName, Date, Time, BarberName, Seat)`

that could translate to this

```
R(A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

what are the dependencies?

Comment: You have to find what is called a *cover* of the functional dependencies holding in the relation, that is a set of functional dependencies from which we can derive all the possible dependences holding in the relation. Note that the candidate keys are determined by the functional dependencies holding on the relation. How did you find those without knowning the functional dependencies?

Comment: Yeah my bad, i mixed it up with another one, ignore the CK:s.

Comment: Show your work following your textbook. Please don't ask us to rewrite it. So how does it tell you to find FDs & where are you stuck in that? See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. "could translate to R(A,B,C,D,E,F)" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.